# Golang question Array sudoku - grid[i][j][0]

Tags: arrays, go, sudoku

Hi I have a doubt with this code exactly with this `seenRow[grid[i][j][0] - 49]`. what does this ?

```golang
func sudoku2(grid [][]string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        var seenRow [9]bool
        var seenCol [9]bool
        var seenSub [9]bool
        for j := 0; j < 9; j++ {
            if grid[i][j] != "." {
                if seenRow[grid[i][j][0] - 49] {
                    return false
                }
                seenRow[grid[i][j][0] - 49] = true
            }
            if grid[j][i] != "." {
                if seenCol[grid[j][i][0] - 49] {
                    return false
                }
                seenCol[grid[j][i][0] - 49] = true
            }
            x := i%3*3 + j%3
            y := i/3*3 + j/3
            if grid[y][x] != "." {
                if seenSub[grid[y][x][0] - 49] {
                    return false
                }
                seenSub[grid[y][x][0] - 49] = true
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seenRow[grid[i][j][0] - 49]
```

`seenRow` is a slice of slice of `string`, hence the first two indices `[i][j]`. `grid[i][j]` is a string, and `grid[i][j][0]` is the numeric value of the first byte value as an integer.

The subtraction `-49` and the 9-element slice `seenRow` makes me think that the string's first byte is a value between 49 and 57 (ascii value '1' to '9'). At this point it's worth looking at the other parts of the code to understand what data is stored in `grid` and what are its semantics.

If I had to guess, `grid` is a 9-by-9 Sudoko board where each value is represented as a 1-byte string with values '1' to '9', with a special value '.' This is a rather odd representation, but it's what the code suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an emulation of a hashmap. 49 is the ASCII character value of character `1`, so if a cell has value `1`, `cell-49` will give 0, if the cell has `2`, `cell-49` will give 1, etc. And `seenSub` array keeps track of which digits were seen. If `seenSub[i]` is `true`, then the digit `i+1` has been seen.